# I created a DB schema for a project relating to collecting comments for web pages, is relational the way to go and how are my relationships?

Tags: mysql, normalization, relational-theory, database-diagrams

[image]

I'm curious if relational DB is the way to go, if the current relationships in the diagram make sense, and whether it will bode well for coding.

Comment: Have you looked that the database relational for stackoverflow? How post and comments relationships are design? That will give you more ideas.

Comment: No, I have not. Where can I locate that resource?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new shows the schema in table form on the right-hand side.

Comment: That's aweseome; never knew about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of cmments:

`CommentReplies` seems to be implementing many-to-many.  I would expect it to be one-to-many -- as in, each comment has one 'parent'.  One-to-many does not need an extra table; you simply have `parent_id` as a column in `Comments`.

Consider using `ENUM` datatype instead of adding a `XxTypes` table.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was actually having an error relating to that many-to-many relationship when using the Forward Engineer tool to create the tables.

Comment: I considered using the `ENUM` datatype, but http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/ made me think makes me reconsider because my ENUMs wouldn't be set in stone, and are subject to change.

Comment: Yes, there are tradeoffs between ENUM, normalization, and other techniques.  (Hence, my use of the word "consider".)

Comment: The "proof of the pudding" is whether the `SELECTs` can be written, and whether they run sufficiently fast when there is lots of data.

Comment: I did indeed note the intelligent usage of the word "consider". Yes, performance is what I'm unsure about, but I guess time will have to tell.

Comment: Performance, ease of adding another item to the list, etc.  I have a strong opinions on many topics, but not on ENUM.  Flip a coin.  Then let it be a learning experience.  The performance hit for `ALTER ... ENUM` was mostly eliminated in 5.1.40 (6 years ago); the "enum-is-evil" blog was probably still assuming ALTER would require a table copy.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. I guess I'll let it be a learning experience then.